# Search utility that searches through source code files

Tags: ruby, file-system, console, search

I'm working on a search utility that searches through source files. It's only the beginning of the project. It lacks a lot of features, but a backbone of the project works and it would be great if you can take a look at it.

```
path, keyword = ARGV if ARGV.length == 2

if ARGV.length != 2
  puts "Not enough argumetns. Type 'finder --help' for help" 
  abort if ARGV.length != 2
end


IGNORED_DIRS = ['..', '.', '.git', 'blib', '_build', '.bzr', '.cdv', 'cover_db',
                '__pycache', 'CVS', '_darcs', '~.dep', '~.dot', '.hg', '~.nib', '.pc', '~.plst', 'RCS', 'SCCS',
               '_sgbak', '.svn', '.tox','.metadata', '.cover']


# colorize output
class String
  def black;          "\033[30m#{self}\033[0m" end
  def red;            "\033[31m#{self}\033[0m" end
  def green;          "\033[32m#{self}\033[0m" end
  def brown;          "\033[33m#{self}\033[0m" end
  def blue;           "\033[34m#{self}\033[0m" end
  def magenta;        "\033[35m#{self}\033[0m" end
  def cyan;           "\033[36m#{self}\033[0m" end
  def gray;           "\033[37m#{self}\033[0m" end
  def bg_black;       "\033[40m#{self}\033[0m" end
  def bg_red;         "\033[41m#{self}\033[0m" end
  def bg_green;       "\033[42m#{self}\033[0m" end
  def bg_brown;       "\033[43m#{self}\033[0m" end
  def bg_blue;        "\033[44m#{self}\033[0m" end
  def bg_magenta;     "\033[45m#{self}\033[0m" end
  def bg_cyan;        "\033[46m#{self}\033[0m" end
  def bg_gray;        "\033[47m#{self}\033[0m" end
  def bold;           "\033[1m#{self}\033[22m" end
  def reverse_color;  "\033[7m#{self}\033[27m" end
end


# convert given path to full path
# which can be used in 'Dir.chdir()'
def expand_path(path)
  case path
  when '.'
    Dir.pwd
  when /~(\/[a-zA-Z\w]*)+/
    File.expand_path(path, __FILE__)    
  when /\.\/[a-z]*/
    Dir.pwd + path[1..-1]
  when /\/[a-z]*/
    Dir.pwd + path
  else
    puts "Wrong path name"
  end
end

def search_in_file(path_to_file, keyword)
  f = open(path_to_file)

  flag = true

  f.each_with_index do |line, i|
    if line.include? keyword

      # print file name and path
      if flag
        puts ""
        puts path_to_file.bold.blue
        flag = false
      end
      puts "#{i+1}:".bold.gray + " #{line}".sub(keyword, keyword.bg_red) 
    end
  end
end

def file_finder(path, keyword)
  Dir.chdir(path)

  entries = Dir.entries('.')

  entries.each do |item|
    unless IGNORED_DIRS.include?(item)
      if File.file?(path + "/" + item)
        search_in_file(path + "/" + item, keyword)
      else
        file_finder(path + "/" + item, keyword)
      end
    end
  end
end

file_finder(expand_path(path), keyword)
```

Comment: Anything in particular you are concerned about?

Comment: I am newcomer to Ruby and my knowledge about language and how should I approach problem using Ruby is very limited right now. So, I just like to hear some feedback, may be some weak points and some improvements I can take. May be some Ruby way of how to do such and such

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The POSIX `grep` command accepts the keyword as the first parameter, then the paths to search as subsequent parameters.  That has the advantage of letting the user specify any number of paths to search.

You misspelled "argumetns".  Also, I recommend writing `"#{File::basename($0)}"` rather than hardcoding `"finder"` as the program name.

It is customary to put all of the class / method definitions first, then all of the "main" code at the end.  You've put the argument-handling code at the top, and the `file_finder(expand_path(path), keyword)` call at the bottom.  Curiously, you test `ARGV.length` in three places — is it really that important?

### `file_finder`

Avoid using `Dir#chdir`, as changing the current directory alters the global state of the process.  One consequence of `Dir#chdir` is that you need to use absolute paths.  For portability, use `File::join(path, item)` instead of `path + "/" + item`.

For efficiency, `IGNORED_DIRS` should be a `Set`.

```
def file_finder(path, keyword)
  Dir.foreach(path) do |item|
    next if IGNORED_DIRS.include?(item)

    item_path = File::join(path, item)
    if File.file?(item_path)
      search_in_file(item_path, keyword)
    else
      file_finder(item_path, keyword)
    end
  end
end
```

### `expand_path`

Your `expand_path` incorrectly treats an absolute path as a relative path.

When expanding a path starting with `~`, I don't see any reason to provide `__FILE__` as the second argument to `File.expand_path`.

In case of an error, you should raise an exception instead of printing a message here.  However, I don't see any reason why there should be an error in the first place.

If you avoid changing directories altogether, then you wouldn't need to generate absolute paths at all.  Then you could just eliminate this function and call `File::expand_path` instead.

### `search_in_file`

Opening a file without closing it causes a file descriptor leak.

`flag` is a poor variable name.

I'm not a fan of augmenting the `String` class, especially for code that is, strictly speaking, related more to terminal control than strings.

```
def search_in_file(path_to_file, keyword)
  seen = false
  File::open(path_to_file) do |f|
    f.each_with_index do |line, i|
      if line.include?(keyword)
        if not seen
          puts path_to_file.bold.blue
          seen = true
        end
        puts "#{i+1}:".bold.gray + " #{line}".sub(keyword, keyword.bg_red)
      end
    end
  end
  puts "" if seen
end
```

Comment: Thank you for **File::join(path, item)** I didn't know about that. I guess if I decided to make my app works on Windows it would be handy.

Comment: in `file_finder`  you said that I should avoid `Dir#chdir`. Could you suggest another ways of doing this?

Comment: I already did. This solution works.

Comment: I like your `file_finder` implementation. It's much robust isn't it?

Comment: does `File::open` prevent File descriptor leaks? If so, how? I don't see any `file.close` at the end

Comment: [`File::open`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.0.0/File.html#method-c-open) says: "If the optional code block is given, it will be passed the opened `file` as an argument and the `File` object will automatically be closed when the block terminates."

Comment: Really great suggestions you gave me,  I really appreciate it. Thanks a lot

Answer (score 3):

- Whenever we make utility type of ruby scripts please make use of [option parser](http://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.2.0/libdoc/optparse/rdoc/OptionParser.html) to deal with options parameter.
- Encompose the methods inside a class. So, that the methods can be written without parameter.